# Override 'Request Start' on an KendoUI MVC ComboBox

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I need to alter a few HTML ELEMENTS prior to each request made by an MVC KendoUI ComboBox - **and I MUST do so from within a JavaScript controller** (not the MVC Code).

**Q:** How can I hook into the 'RequestStart' from an existing DataSource?

**JAVASCRIPT CONTROLLER:** 
I am only showing the initialize method here...

```
var initialize = function (options) {
    that.settings = $.extend(empty, $.isPlainObject(options) ? options : empty);

    // Elements
    var ddlPrimaryCircuitPath = $(dictionary.selectors.ddlPrimaryCircuitPath, dictionary.elements.form);

    // Kendo Objects
    var primaryCircuitPath = $(dictionary.selectors.ddlPrimaryCircuitPath, dictionary.elements.form).data('kendoComboBox');

    // Events
    // THIS DOESNT WORK EITHER
    primaryCircuitPath.bind('requestStart', function(){
        console.log('requestStart: you did it.');
    });
}
```

**MVC OBJECT DEFINITION:** 
I cannot alter this in any way...

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
  .Name("ddlSecondaryCiruitPath")
  .Filter("contains")
  .Placeholder("Select Circuit Path...")
  .DataTextField("CircuitFullName")
  .DataValueField("Circuit.Id")
  .AutoBind(false)
  .MinLength(4)
  .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("listcircuitdata", "api/dataitem", new { area = "" }))
        .ServerFiltering(true))
  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%;" }))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`requestStart` is a dataSource event, not a ComboBox event. So replace this:

```
primaryCircuitPath.bind('requestStart', function(){
    console.log('requestStart: you did it.');
});
```

with this:

```
primaryCircuitPath.dataSource.bind('requestStart', function(){
    console.log('requestStart: you did it.');
});
```

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox#fields-dataSource

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#events-requestStart

Comment: WINNER, WINNER, CHICKEN DINNER !!!  Thanks for actually reading the question in-full :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can handle datasource "RequestStart" event by setting datasource's event parameter clientside like this:

```
@(
    Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
    .Name("ddlSecondaryCiruitPath")
    .Filter("contains")
    .Placeholder("Select Circuit Path...")
    .DataTextField("CircuitFullName")
    .DataValueField("Circuit.Id")
    .AutoBind(false)
    .MinLength(4)
    .DataSource(source =>
        {
            source.Read(read =>
            {
                read.Action("listcircuitdata", "api/dataitem", new { area = "" });
            });
            source.Events(e => e.RequestStart("JSHandler"));
        })
)
```

You can set some specific events over your grid from JS as following, but I'm not sure it would help you

```
(function ($, kendo) {
        $.extend(true, kendo.ui.validator, {
            rules: {
                equalto: function (input) {
                    if (input.filter("[data-val-equalto-other]").length) {
                        var otherField = input.attr("data-val-equalto-other");
                        otherField = otherField.substr(otherField.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
                        return input.val() == $("#" + otherField).val();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            },
            messages: {
                equalto: function (intput) {
                    return intput.attr("data-val-equalto");
                }
            }
        });
    })(jQuery, kendo);
```

Comment: I'm not sure you read the BOLD LETTERING in the first line of my question - I cannot alter the MVC definition